# Where does PHP get it's DATE information from?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I live in the UK and the current time is 02:30am on Monday 10th Feb 2014, however, my website is showing 02:30am Sunday 9th Feb 2014 - the day and date where the same before midnight so i am assuming a timezone difference.  Can i set this to my own timezone ?

edit: Can i set this to the users' timezone?

Comment: shouldn't be a timezone problem. See if your date interpretation is off by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look like a timezone issue since the date if off by a full 24 hours. But just in case it is, it is set in your php.ini, and of that is not set, it defaults to the server time zone.

You can set it in your php.ini file by setting [`date.timezone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) to be the timezone of your choosing.

```
date.timezone = Europe/London;
```

If you don't have access to the php.ini you can use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the timezone in your scripts.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Comment: oh wow, i didn't know this was a command, thank you - this works for me, but why wouldn't it automatically pick up the user's own date? and  do you know how i can get it to do this please ?

Comment: PHP won't really know what the user's local date/time is. But [this solution](http://trevoro.net/2013/whats-your-timezone/) looks very good.

Comment: Maybe a long *(inaccurate)* way: Detect user's IP using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, use IP geolocation services to get country, then serve appropriate timezone for that country.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to define the timezone you want:

1. [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');`
2. Modifying your **php.ini**: `date.timezone = Asia/Manila`

Answer (score 1):

In code, you can see what the default timezone is by calling [`date_default_timezone_get()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php). You can set it programatically using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). The preferred way to do it though is to use the php.ini settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set the timezone preference in the php.ini file that initializes the PHP environment *or* if you don't have access to anything like that, you could look into http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php