# Getting time in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, time

When I output a date in php or javascript, how is it calculated? Is it affected by the time a user has set on his computer or is it taken from an external source? If the user can affect it, then how do I make sure my code gets the real date/time?

Comment: `PHP` get the time from the server on which it's running. 
`JavaScript` get the time from the users device as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in technology and the context of these technologies. Meaning front-end (client side) or back-end (server side). The difference in `PHP` and `JavaScript` are on the level of invokement.

**`PHP`**

`PHP` is run on a dedicated server, not a clients machine. When the time function is invoked from within the `PHP` context, the time will be taken from the server side. Meaning the time of the hosting server.

**`JavaScript`**

`JavaScript` is running at client side level (browser). Time taken within the  `JavaScript` context will take the clients operating system time. Changing your operating system time settings will have effect on your `JavaScript` time fetching.

In this case we are not taking into account any `JavaScript` back-end, like `NodeJS`. Since this behaves as the above mentioned `PHP`context.

Whenever I need to ensure correct Date/Time on a client side `JavaScript` application, I'll launch a REST request to retrieve the server time. Counting on the server time takes into account that only authenticated system admin's have control on the server Data/Time settings. And we can rely on this Date/Time truth.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript gets it from the users clock

[Where does javascript get a new date from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581421/where-does-javascript-get-a-new-date-from)

PHP gets it from the Server

[Where does PHP get its date information from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668157/where-does-php-get-its-date-information-from)